# How to read a file without header or footer using itextsharp?

Tags: c#

How do I remove header and footer from pages in existing PDF files using itextsharp ?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(myfile);
// here I want to get the text without any header or footer if it is possible
string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

**Note:**

the file may or may not contain header and footer